# How to add active class in pagination

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have code for pagination but failed to active class. I want the click able page will be active. How can I do that with the bellow code?

```
<?php 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM item "; 
    $rs_result = mysqli_query($con,$sql); //run the query
    $total_records = mysqli_num_rows($rs_result);  //count number of records
    $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $num_rec_per_page); 
    echo "<nav >
    <ul class='pagination'><li class='disabled'>
    <a href='myminsingbazar-en.php?Page=allAds&page=1'>".'&laquo;'."</a> </li>"; // Goto 1st page  
    for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 
    echo "<li><a href='myminsingbazar-en.php?Page=allAds&page=".$i."'>".$i."</a></li>"; 
    }; 
    echo "<li class='disabled'><a href='myminsingbazar-en.php?Page=allAds&page=$total_pages'>".'&raquo;'."</a> </li>
    </ul>
    </nav>"; // Goto last page
?>
```

Comment: just add a checker `if($_GET['page'] == $i) add some active class`

Comment: I code it but show error
echo "<li <? if($_GET['page']==$i){?>class='active'<? }?>><li/>



Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number

Comment: @moni update your whole answer so one can check where the error is...

Comment: @Nishant I just want to ad active class in <li> list. I try but all the list active. plz code me . It will be highly appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this code...

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM item ";
$rs_result = mysqli_query($con, $sql); //run the query
$total_records = mysqli_num_rows($rs_result);  //count number of records
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / $num_rec_per_page);
echo "<nav>
    <ul class='pagination'><li class='disabled'>
    <a href='myminsingbazar-en.php?Page=allAds&page=1'>" . '&laquo;' . "</a> </li>"; // Goto 1st page  
for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++)
{
    $active = '';
    if(isset($_GET['page']) && $i == $_GET['page'])
    {
        $active = 'class="active"';        
    }
    echo "<li $active><a href='myminsingbazar-en.php?Page=allAds&page=" . $i . "'>" . $i . "</a></li>";
};
echo "<li class='disabled'><a href='myminsingbazar-en.php?Page=allAds&page=$total_pages'>" . '&raquo;' . "</a> </li>
    </ul>
    </nav>"; // Goto last page
?>
```

let me know if you need any further help..

Comment: Sorry @Nishant I am new here . How can I vote you so that You get +15 reputation . I click tick sign but when I click up button it shows error, give massage that you need 15 reputation. I am glad to u really